# Resizing / scale a vector-PDF on a webserver via PHP et cetera

Tags: php, image, pdf, vector

I would like to solve the following task:

I want to scale a PDF-file in a server-environment (PHP, Perl, ImageMagick, FPDF, etc.). The file consists of vector sprites and needs to be scaled non-linearely (X= AA %; Y = BB% of the original size).

I would like to use something like Image Magick for it, since I have experience with that and it's fairly easy. Actually, this *is* possible with Magick but Magick can't output the file as PDF/vector again.

The process should work fully automatically; the user uploads a vector-PDF and this shall be converted (scaled) directly on the server.

I searched a lot but I did not found an appropriate answer to this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you have the wrong idea about what vector graphics really means. You mean you want to *resize* the original PDF? Imagemagick will only be able to output a fixed sized raster image based on your PDF.

You can use a PHP PDF library like Zend_Pdf to actually change properties such as resizing of the PDF document.

Comment: Well, resize is the wrong / not the precise word since vector-sprites don't have fixes sizes. As described, I want to change the width and height of the page / the objects on the page to a certain percentage of the original size, but independent; X should scale A% down, Y should scale B% down. I will have a look into Zend_Pdf; thanks!